# Can Google Sheets use Conditional Formatting to validate an entry through vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm stumped and could be overthinking this. I have a sheet that has a Check tab and Invoice tab. Any checks that arrive, whether they be for an Invoice or not, are tracked on the Check tab while any Invoices sent out with expected amount due are on the Invoice tab.

On the Check tab, we have a conditional format that validates if an Invoice received with a check is a valid Invoice number; Col C. In the next column, we enter the amount received. I'd like to have Conditional Formatting validate if the amount entered matches what was expected for payment. Valid, no color. Invalid, red.

[Check Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHdSN.png)

Is there a way to do this? Using Conditional Format to validate an entry via vlookup?

Thank you!!
[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZVVmou3kTECs7hIcL_UdTBrgNZVqref60e6BGqud_mo/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried entering this formula into Conditional Formatting on the Check Tab but nothing happens.
=D2=vlookup(D2,indirect("Invoices!$c$4:d"),2,0)

I also tried researching Index/Match with Conditional Formatting but I'm not seeing anything that's similar enough to this need.

Answer (score 1):

*Slightly modifying your formula with:*

```js
=$D4<>vlookup($C4,indirect("Invoices!$C$4:$D"),2,)
```

[image]

Comment: You rock! Thank you rockinfreakshow!